# solve integral symbolic in Matlab

Tags: matlab, integral

I would like to symbolically solve an integral in Matlab. But Matlab doesn't solve my equation.

The term I want to take integral is : x ^2 * exp(-lambda*x)/ (x+w+tau)

Here is my code:

```
syms x 
f = x ^2 * exp(-lambda*x)/ (x+w+tau);
F = int(f,0,lambda)
pretty(F)
```

Matlab does not solve it, instead gives me the folowing:

```
F =
 
int((x^2*exp(-lambda*x))/(tau + w + x), x, 0, lambda)
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a closed-form expression for that integral?

Comment: What are `lambda`, `w` and `tau`? In any case, you can find a numerical solution if those 3 are numbers and you do `double(F)`